# Подсветка удалённых комментариев

Tags: дефект, дизайн, инструменты-модератора

У подсвечиваемой области удалённого комментария неверная ширина. Причём заметно, что подсветка *пересекает* число плюсов на комментарии.

Highlighted area of deleted comment has a wrong width. You can even see that it *crosses* number of upvotes on the comment.

[image: скриншот удалённых комментариев]

В случае же с подсветкой при переходе по прямой ссылке всё верно.

But an active comment (because of direct link) is highlighted correctly.

[image: скриншот :target]

PS: Комментарии на скриншоте удалены автором как неактуальные в связи с написанием ответа на их основе.

PS: Comments on the screenshot are deleted by their author as obsolete after posting an answer based on them.